# How do I use a crossbow as a warrior?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was wondering how to use the crossbow on my human warrior.

Could someone please help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Hunter is the only class (that I know of) that can use crossbows. You'll have to visit your faction's Weapons Trainer to ask to teach you how to use crossbows (you need to be at least lvl 10 or 20 depending on the weapon type; crossbows should be 10, I think). If the teacher you visit does not teach crossbows, then ask him who does.

Comment: @nolonar You no longer need to train your weapon skills at a Weapons Trainer. They are now part of your innate abilities when you start. Warriors and Rogues can also use crossbows, but doing so hinder their ability to do damage significantly as they have to unequip their melee weapon(s) in order to equip the crossbow.

Comment: This information can be obtained easily on the Internet. Sorry -1 for lack of research. Totally valid question, but poor research. http://wowpedia.org/Crossbow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only hunters, warriors and rogues can use crossbows. Hunters' abilities are tuned to make use of ranged weapons, whereas warriors and rogues need to sacrifice a huge chunk of their damage when they equip a crossbow as their skills make use of melee weapons.

A crossbow goes in the same slot used for melee weapons (post-patch-5.0.4). It is considered a two-handed weapon.

In order to shoot with the equipped bow, simply right click on the target to autoattack, or left click on the target and select a skill such as Steady Shot.

[Further reading](http://wowpedia.org/Crossbow)